# Namespace php cannot find class

Tags: php, namespaces, php-5.5

I have structure

```
   one.php
   src
     two.php
```

one.php file

```
 <?php
        function autoloadSrc($class){
        $class = preg_replace('#\\\\#',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $class);
        if (file_exists('src' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php'))
                require_once('src' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php');
       }

        spl_autoload_register('autoloadSrc');
        $a= new src\Agg();
        echo $a -> $b;
    ?>
```

two.php file

```
<?php
    namespace src;

        class Agg{
            public $b = "hi"
        }
    ?>
```

yet i recieve error that it cannot find class Agg in one.php file , what am i doing wrong

Comment: Are you using some kind of autoloader?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: So no relationship between the filename `two.php` and the classname `Agg`?

Comment: @MarkBaker i do not undertand what you mean by that

Comment: Your file is called `two.php`.... how does the autoloader know that class `Agg` is in file `two.php`? The autoloader is looking for a file called `src\Agg.php`

Comment: i tried to rename two.php to Agg.php but error remains the same

Comment: And you won't find `src\src\Agg.php`